# TypeError: .default.auth.signout is not a function in REACT and Firebase

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-authentication

I can see a lot of the same error questions on StackOverflow but Mostly are not answered and the answered one doesn't really help me. Please help to debug out this error.

I am implementing a Login/Signup in my REACT project using firebase. The code Compiles Successfully but shows an error in the browser.
The Error is
***TypeError: *fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10*_.default.auth.signout is not a function***

Here is My App.js (ignore the commented part as its part of my project but not related to this)

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
/*import Home from "./components/pages/Home"
import About from './components/pages/About';
import Contact from './components/pages/Contact';*/
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch}from 'react-router-dom';
/*import Error from './components/pages/Error';
import AddBooking from './components/Bookings/AddBooking';
import EditBooking from './components/Bookings/EditBooking';
import ViewBooking from './components/Bookings/ViewBooking';
import Bookings from './components/pages/Bookings';*/
import Login from './components/pages/login';
import fire from './fire';

function App() {

    const[user, setUser]= useState('');
    const[email, setEmail]= useState('');
    const[password, setPassword]= useState('');
    const[emailError, setEmailError]= useState('');
    const[passwordError, setPasswordError]= useState('');
    const[hasAccount, setHasAccount]= useState(false);

    const clearInputs=()=>{
        setEmail('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    const clearErrors=()=>{
        setEmailError('');
        setPasswordError('');
    }

    const handleLogin=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                case "auth/user-disabled":
                case "auth/user-not-found":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/wrong-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleSignup=()=>{
        clearErrors();
        fire
        .auth()
        .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
        .catch((err)=>{                             
            switch(err.code){
                case "auth/email-already-in-use":
                case "auth/invalid-email":
                    setEmailError(err.message);
                    break;
                case "auth/weak-password":
                    setPasswordError(err.message);
                    break;
            }
        });
    };

    const handleLogout=()=>{
        fire.auth.signout();
    };

    const authListener=()=>{
        fire.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user=>{
            if(user){
                clearInputs();
                setUser(user);
            }else{
                setUser('');
            }
        });
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
        authListener();
    }, []);

  
  return (
    <Router>
    {user?(
        //<Router>
        <Navbar handleLogout={handleLogout}/>
        /*<Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home}/>
            <Route exact path="/Bookings" component={Bookings}/>
            <Route exact path="/about" component={About}/>
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact}/>
            <Route exact path="/Bookings/add" component={AddBooking}/>
            <Route exact path="/Bookings/edit/:id" component={EditBooking}/>
            <Route exact path="/Bookings/view/:id" component={ViewBooking}/>
            <Route component={Error}/>
        </Switch>
        </Router>*/
    ):(
        <Login 
        email={email} 
        setEmail={setEmail}
        password={password}
        setPassword={setPassword}
        handleLogin={handleLogin}
        handleSignup={handleSignup}
        hasAccount={hasAccount}
        setHasAccount={setHasAccount}
        emailError={emailError}
        passwordError={passwordError}
        />
    )}
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am seeing your handleLogout function has typo?

Your code

```
const handleLogout=()=>{
    fire.auth.signout();
};
```

You might need to call auth function itself as you do in other part of code, e.g. handleLogIn function,
This would fix your signout error unless you don't have other issue in your code,

```
const handleLogout=()=>{
    fire.auth().signOut();
};
```

Comment: It still shows the same error-- TypeError: _fire__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_5__.default.auth(...).signout is not a function

Comment: For proper scope, other firebase auth functions are working properly?

Comment: Yes Login Worked fine

Comment: Everytime I start my project on local server using mon start. Its already Logged in. and I can't logout now. How to manage this and Signout is showing error

Comment: Did you fix your handleLogout function inside?
As I submitted on my answer, you have some problem to call auth, you need to call auth function itself, not like nested object

Comment: Can you share your fire.js as well in your question?

Comment: Is it safe to share fire.js? I don't know!

Comment: Yes I fixed fire.auth.signout(); to fire.auth().signout();

Comment: Then can you update your question with that also along with fire.js file?

Comment: The problem was fixed; Actually there was nothing wrong in fire.js. I changed fire.auth().signout(); to fire.auth().signOut(); and everything was sorted. It was a typo. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: Congrats, I updated the answer, similar to my suggestion. :), Please feel free to accept my answer,